# Can't open a thread for a big process

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm currently working on a CAO software, with C++.

I want to multithread one of my process, using std::thread from C++11 (I have tried with winbase thread). This process calls a geometrical function, and needs a lot of memory, especially with big models. Each thread works on its proper model, and it can be many models in the scene. This function doesn't concern displaying models, it's just computations.

It works perfectly fine on many cases, for example with many little models, or few big models. But when i try to apply my process with many big models, all the threads don't want to start (it crashes when i try to create the first one).

I tried with WinBase thread, but it failed to open a new thread (it was returning NULL). I was on VS2010. So, I then tried with VS2012 and std::thread but now, I have a runtime error.

Here is the part of the code where the thread is created:

```
std::thread * threadOp;
try
{
             threadOp = new  thread(method ,argument);
}
catch ( const std::exception & e )
{
             std::cerr << e.what(); 
}
```

Changing the number of thread at a same time doesn't change anything, it's just the number of models or their size which is important.

Again, it crashes right at the creation of the thread, and not in looping function ( method ).

I've searched on the internet without getting any results.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: it's very strange that it is fails, because you don't even join the thread, you need `threadOp->join(); or threadOp->detach();` and can you write the backtrace of it fail.

Comment: I use threadOp->join() later on the code, but it crashes before. I cannot go further than the creation of the thread.

Comment: Previously, there was only one thread ( the application's thread). There were no problems there. But with the same models, and many threads, it crashes at the creation of the thread.

I can specify the number of thread allowed at a time, and it works only if i choose one thread.

But for example, with 2 or more threads, it will be fine on a scene with 12 same models, but it will crash at the creation of the thread in a scene with 24 models (these models are all the same).

Parameters I pass at the creation of threads are vectors, I already have checked their integrity.

Comment: Are you trying to copy-contruct a very large argument onto the stack of the new thread by value, by any chance?  If so, stop doing it:)

Comment: These vectors are passed by their address. There are just two ints.

Comment: Why are you creating the `std::thread` on the heap? `std::thread` is a value type, you can pass it around by value and rely on move semantics to transfer ownership between objects. That's usually preferable.

Comment: mb there is problem with access?? do you use mutex or smth like that?

Comment: I use semaphore, but i don't use any mutex. I think with VS2010 and winbase it was a problem of access, that's why I have changed for std::thread with VS2012 instead of winbase thread.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Unknow exception (with `e.what()`). With winbase, the handle returned by the `CreateThread` function was NULL.

Comment: Hi, with `std::cout << "Type:    " << typeid(e).name() << "\n";` instead of `e.what()`, i have "scheduler_resource_allocation_error". Any idea?